# Fire meet gasoline: is it correct?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, songs

Is it grammatically correct to say "Fire meet gasoline", as in the Sia's song,  or just poetic license??

> "Flame and candle meet, fire meet gasoline
>
> Fire meet gasoline, I'm burnin' alive
>
> I can barely breathe, when you're here loving me
>
> Fire meet gasoline, fire meet gasoline"

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about 'Dad, meet grandma', and it might even make sense in some contexts. This might be a non-standard version of 'fire meets gasoline'. It's certainly unidiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Don't know how to ping you in the relevant place, so am doing so here and will then delete this comment. I think this post that you originally close-voted might actually be of interest to you, now that the salient points have been edited into the question. I think I remember you raising the *have* point under a post of mine at some point ... ? [What's the object of this sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249127/what-is-the-object-of-the-cat-ran-out-the-door?noredirect=1#comment542257_249127)

Comment: An unclear construction or punctuation. It should be either Fire, meet gasoline  ( meet as imperative) or: Fire meets gasoline (a statement). But it is no use  seeing song texts too critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout the [lyric](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enUS630US630&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fire%20meet%20gasoline%20lyrics) a woman addresses a new lover, inviting him to "Burn me", "Strike the match", building to the lines

> Fire meet gasoline
>   Burn with me tonight
>   And we will fly
>   Like smoke

That is, she portrays him as the fire and herself as the gasoline. It's pretty clear that the phrase is to be understood as an imperative, an "introduction" of herself to him, not as a narrative predication.

Answer (score 4):

It's really "Fire, meet gasoline", where the speaker is speaking to someone named 'Fire' or the object of fire personified. Then the speaker uses the imperative 'meet' with the object being again a personified object of Gasoline.

It could be modified slightly, preserving the original constituents, to

> "Fire, my man, please meet my old pal Gasoline".

Comment: You know, not that it matters but rather than "Fire, meet gasoline" you could possibly interpret it as a sort of command, or dramatic reflection, given in a sort of fragmentary poetic "cave-man grammar style".  "Fire meet gasoline!"  "Black meet white!"  "Plus touch minus!"  "Young versus old!"   (Begun, have these clone wars!) Or you could say a sort of rasta-grammar style.  "What happen when me and that guy got together mon? Fire meet gasoline!"

Answer (score 2):

The structure is grammatic, especially with the addition of a comma, as StoneyB indicated.

As a poetic image, it can be paraphrased (roughly) as "You are fire, I am gasoline. Guess what's going to happen when we get together?". Since it's part of the larger verse, this is approximate.